# is cvCeil() faster than standard library?

Tags: c++, optimization, std

I see that OpenCV implement `cvCeil` function:

```
CV_INLINE  int  cvCeil( double value )
{
#if defined _MSC_VER && defined _M_X64 || (defined __GNUC__ && defined __SSE2__&& !defined __APPLE__)
    __m128d t = _mm_set_sd( value );
    int i = _mm_cvtsd_si32(t);
    return i + _mm_movemask_pd(_mm_cmplt_sd(_mm_cvtsi32_sd(t,i), t));
#elif defined __GNUC__
    int i = (int)value;
    return i + (i < value);
#else
    int i = cvRound(value);
    float diff = (float)(i - value);
    return i + (diff < 0);
#endif
}
```

I'm curious in this implementations first part, i.e. the `_mm_set_sd` related calls. Will they be faster than MSVCRT / libstdc++ / libc++ ? And why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple benchmark below tells me that `std::round` works more than 3 times faster on my SSE4-enabled machine, but about 2 times slower when SSE4 is not enabled.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/fast_math.hpp>

auto currentTime() { return std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); }

template<typename T, typename P>
std::string toString(std::chrono::duration<T,P> dt)
{
    std::ostringstream str;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    str << duration_cast<microseconds>(dt).count()*1e-3 << " ms";
    return str.str();
}

int main()
{
    volatile double x=34.234;
    volatile double y;
    constexpr auto MAX_ITER=100'000'000;
    const auto t0=currentTime();
    for(int i=0;i<MAX_ITER;++i)
        y=std::ceil(x);
    const auto t1=currentTime();
    for(int i=0;i<MAX_ITER;++i)
        y=cvCeil(x);
    const auto t2=currentTime();
    std::cout << "std::ceil: " << toString(t1-t0) << "\n"
                 "cvCeil   : " << toString(t2-t1) << "\n";
}
```

I test with `-O3` option on GCC 8.3.0, glibc-2.27, Ubuntu 18.04.1 x86_64 on Intel Core i7-3930K 3.2 GHz.

Output when compiled with `-msse4`:

```
std::ceil: 39.357 ms
cvCeil   : 143.224 ms
```

Output when compiled without `-msse4`:

```
std::ceil: 274.945 ms
cvCeil   : 146.218 ms
```

It's easy to understand: SSE4.1 introduces the `ROUNDSD` instruction, which is basically what `std::round` does. Before this the compiler has to do some comparison/conditional-moves tricks, and it also has to make sure that these don't overflow. Thus the `cvCeil` version, sacrificing well-definedness for `value>INT_MAX` and for `value<INT_MIN`, gets speedup for the values for which it's well-defined. For others it has undefined behavior (or, with intrinsics, simply gives wrong results).